# lldb can not show list on mac os 10.12

Tags: c++, macos, clang, lldb

I was trying to use lldb to debug c++ code and found that the debugger is not able to show the value of a list. As shown in the attached figure, the list is initialized with {1 ,2, 3}. Yet the debugger is showing some random value. I am using macos 10.12. The lldb version is lldb-900.0.64. The clang version is Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2).[image: debug_list_lldb]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pniXz.png)

Comment: The data formatter for std::list got the count right, but didn't show the elements.  I don't remember any bugs with the list formatter in lldb-900 but that version is a little old, and my memory is only so-so...  lldb prints the list correctly for your example with current lldb & clang, both from Xcode 10.2 and TOT llvm.org sources, so if you need this to work you'll probably have to upgrade your tools.